# How to restrict access to particular IP address or domain in laravel web application?

Tags: php, security, laravel-5, copy-protection

Can anyone share me any idea (**free**) that I can make my **Laravel** Application (costumer website) usable to only single IP or domain?

After I host the application into my client's end, I want my code to be secured from being used again for other projects.

*I want to prevent my client from re-publish my code*

**for example**: remote confirmed from my web service for Client IP (costumer website)

Comment: If you stuff is physically held by someone else, you're out of luck. The music/movie/TV industries spent *billions* of dollars on technology to prevent copying. None of it worked more than a few months at best. If your client takes your IP and resells it, sue them. If you don't trust the client, host the application for them and don't give them access to the code.

Answer (score 4):

> After I host the application into my client's end, I want my code to be secured from being used again for other projects.

What you're looking for is a legal protection, not a technological one.

This is related to [the "problem" of client authenticity](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/03/client-authenticity-is-not-server-s-problem) in that you cannot generally control the contents of the computer that's communicating with you. Any copy-protection mechanisms you install will be trivially bypassed. (I work with cryptography; I've seen a lot of attempts to be clever, and none of them have ever stopped me from bypassing or disabling them.)

> Can anyone share me any idea (**free**) that I can make my **Laravel** Application (costumer website) usable to only single IP or domain?

The way that's worded sounds like you're asking StackOverflow to give you free work (or point you to a free alternative to snakeoil solutions like ionCube) which is not what this website is for.